# Laravel - ajax post and go to another view with data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I´ve searching but with no luck, i´ve tried implementing many things but nothing lead to success, so this is my scenario:

At certain point the user is in a view where after filling some fields, he has the ability to **save** or **save and create**.

The first one it is working ok, i´m posting with ajax to my controller method and returning a json response, but the user stays normally in the same view.

The second one(when he saves and create) i´m sending a variable to say exactly that, and because of that choice, **the user must be directed to another view to "create" BUT i need the data that was previously saved to automatically fill some fields on the new form** that is suppose to be created...so my code is:

**my ajax:**

```
$.ajax({
     method: 'POST',
     url: '/Cliente/insertEditCliente',
     dataType: "json",
     data: {"_token": "{{ csrf_token()}}", "mainId":$('#mainId').val(),values,"btnId":this.text},
     success: function(response){
        if(response.titulo != "Erro!"){
          let dados = response['dados'];
          window.location = '{{ route("formAngariacao",[null]) }}'+'/?dados='+dados;
                    }
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { // What to do if we fail
                    // console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                    // console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
                }
            });
```

**in my controller method, i have that if statment to detect if it was just save or save and create:**

```
if($request->post('btnId') == "Guardar"){
                return response()->json(["titulo"=>"Ok!","mensagem"=>"Cliente Alterado com sucesso!","tipo"=>"success"]);
            }
            else{
                return response()->json(["titulo"=>"Ok!","mensagem"=>"Cliente Alterado com sucesso!","tipo"=>"success","dados"=>$request]);
            }
```

But now, in my blade view, i **need to read that array "dados"** which corresponds to the $request variable and has all the data i need.

**How do i do that? and is this the best practice?**

thanks for your time reagards.

Comment: Would it not be better to have the Save button run the Ajax and the Save & Close button post to a different route that has a controller that saves the element and then directs the user to a new view. This way you can use the Laravel validation and stay on the page if there are issues with the form instead of catching all that manually?

Comment: Hi, petay87 thanks for answering. Wouldn´t that be duplicating code? because it´s SAVE and then go to another view, so i still need the code which is in my controller method to save the data...even so, because i´m also going to use ajax, my problem in how to pass the data to the view blade still persists, i don´t know how to do it

Comment: Not if you have the save code as it's own function that could be called from both route's controller functions.